# Connect to compute engine from cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I would like to call a function on compute engine from cloud function.
I have a cloud function that gets triggered when a new file is dropped in cloud storage. I have a python function on compute engine that would process that file. How can I connect to compute engine from cloud function using python. Doesnt have to be using internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

The most recommended and secure way is to use the private IP to reach your compute engine. For this, you can use a [serverless VPC connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) in your Cloud Function.

Now, to allow your function to call your Compute Engine and to launch a process on it, your have (I think) 2 solutions.

1. The most recommended is to expose a simple flask server on your Compute Engine, and thus a simple HTTP service. This service triggers your Python code on the Compute Engine.
2. I think that you can find a Python lib to load in your Cloud Functions and to connect into your Compute Engine with SSH. Not sure, and it's not a good solution/pattern. I recommend you to not loose time on this.